# Is it possible to attribute a wiki post to a user?

Tags: discussion, original-poster

This is a real scenario (but hypothetical at the moment), and a little complicated. Please bear with me...

This question, on 3D printing, *[Anet A8 reading 739°C from the extruder thermistor!](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/anet-a8-reading-739c-from-the-extruder-thermistor)* had [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/anet-a8-reading-739c-from-the-extruder-thermistor#answer-6143) which should have been a *new* question (referring back to the original question).

This new question (which was posted as an answer) received an answer in the form of comments. It should be noted that both the question-in-an-answer *and* the answer-in-the-comments were/are useful additions to the site.

I notified the user, by way of comments, that they should have posted a new question, and that they were free to do so. I also notified them that their answer would be converted to a comment on the original question, and that the answer in the comments would also be converted likewise (and the user who posted the answer-in-the-comments was notified also).

I waited a few days, nothing happened, so I converted the wrongly posted answer (and its comments) to [comments of the OP's question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/anet-a8-reading-739c-from-the-extruder-thermistor#comment9221_5097).

A week or two later, the user has still not reposted a new question, so I have taken the wrongly posted question, and re-posted it as a community-wiki question, [How to use an Anet A8 control board with a damaged AVR IC?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6247/how-to-use-an-anet-a8-control-board-with-a-damaged-avr-ic) Likewise, the answer in the comment, I posted as a [community-wiki answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6247/how-to-use-an-anet-a8-control-board-with-a-damaged-avr-ic#answer-6248).

I did this so as to make the information more visible and not hidden/buried within the comments. This whole process was discussed with other moderators, and agreed upon as a suitable solution to the issue.

So far, so good - I think.

Now, for the hypothetical issue: What happens if the poster of the question-in-an-answer asks whether they can have the community-wiki status removed and have the ownership to the wiki-question passed over to them? Is that possible?  Likewise, if the poster of the answer-in-the-comment asks the same for the wiki-answer, what can be done?

Note that:

- I am not asking how to remove the wiki status and have my [brief] ownership returned (that I know how to do).
- I am not asking how to have the ownership of a question forced upon a user - which obviously they may not agree to, and that sort of mechanism would be wrong.

I am asking how, upon request, to transfer ownership of a post. Is that possible?

I hope that I have described the situation clearly. The community wiki is a bit of a red herring, as that mechanism is just being used to store the information. The issue is that if I wrote a post, can I then, change the authorship of that post, to someone else (with their permission, or upon their request)? Does such a mechanism exist?

Comment: @user134300 yes, it's [being used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311899/152859). Same on MSO. Not common, but they surely use it.