# Homepage showing "answered by Joe" but it wasn't

Tags: bug, homepage, last-activity

Noticed this in MSE homepage:

> [image]

However, [clicking it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ends-on-july-25-2018/311889#311889) resulted in this:

> [image]

That's no Joe. Both employees, both with diamond, but different people with separate accounts.

Joe did accept the answer, but I never seen it causing the last activity to change to the accepter.

What's going on?

Comment: Are you *sure* they're different people?  Ever seen them in the same room together?

Comment: Oh no... another Joe! Joe Overflow! :D

Comment: @Joe which one is the super-hero, and which the secret indentity?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Admittedly that’s why I clicked on the question ...

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363974/why-is-the-wrong-answerer-shown-on-the-front-page/363975#363975

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was answered by Joe, but afterwards he realized that accepting his own answer doesn't pin it to the top of the other answers as expected, so it was... reassigned.

Comment: reassigned?? Black magic? Anyway this also explain this weirdness: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ije27.png

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh that's easily fixed with some more black magic. ;P

Comment: Ha!  I saw that same oddity on the front page and said "hmm, acceptance doesn't do that; I wonder if they hacked things directly in the DB, but why would they do that?".